# Using WCF Message

Tags: wcf, message

I am still confused when it is appropriate to use the Message type in WCF like below

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    Message GetData();

    [OperationContract]
    void PutData(Message m);
}
```

Why would you want to use it?

Can you use it for streaming?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the reasons listed by Tim are valid, we use messages directly in our services to create one uber routing service.
we have one service that can take any method call you throw at it, Clients are generated by wsdls supplied from multiple sources.

This service would take the message, examine its content and route it accordingly. 
So in my opinion if you want to get closer to the wire, or when you dont know the type of incoming messages, you can use the message in the signature directly.

Streaming is a separate concept than message signature, streaming is supported by wcf under very specific bindings and security mechanism and the method signature has to be very specific (i.e it should return/accept stream). Also in streaming the actual stream of data travels outside the scope of soap message.

Comment: Doesn't WCF4 introduce Routing Service made specifically for Routing? Or is the Message packet just another way of doing this

Comment: it does, but to other wcf services only, we have very customized routing behaviors ....

Answer (score 4):

MSDN lists the follow reasons for using the message class directly:

1. When you need an alternative way of creating outgoing message contents (for example, creating a message directly from a file on disk) instead of serializing .NET Framework objects.
2. When you need an alternative way of using incoming message contents (for example, when you want to apply an XSLT transformation to the raw XML contents) instead of deserializing into .NET Framework objects.
3. When you need to deal with messages in a general way regardless of message contents (for example, when routing or forwarding messages when building a router, load-balancer, or a publish-subscribe system).

See [Using the Message Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx) for more detailed information.

**Edit to address the streaming question**

I didn't find a definitive answer in my quick scan via google, but the article above states "All communication between clients and services ultimately results in Message instances being sent and received" - so I would assume it could be used directly in streaming.

Comment: Honestly I have problems understanding those answers. Like point 1, why do you need a message structure to send a message from a file. Could you load the file and just and set up properties in a simple .net class? Sorry if I'm slow

Comment: Also if point 3 could be clarified to that would be great. Not sure using the message structure can help you load balance?

Comment: Another good example of point 2, would be a POX (Plain Old Xml) service in which you were not sure about what the contents was until it arrived.